# TypeError without a clue

Tags: python, typeerror

```
student_scores = input('Input a list of student scores: ')
for n in range(0, len(student_scores)):
    student_scores[n] = int(student_scores[n])
print(student_scores)

highest = 0
for scores in student_scores:
    if highest < scores:
        highest = scores
print(f'The highest score is {highest}')
```

I'm learning the basic of Python and input the code accurately that the tutorial video says, but only mine gets TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment on the line 3.
I checked it several times, but still have no clue why.

Comment: `student_scores` is a string. `str` type is immutable. As the error says it does not support item assignment. You need to convert the user input to list or simply create new list while iterarting over user input while convert to int.

Comment: You ask for a "list of student scores". What, exactly, should the format look like?

Answer (score 1):

The `input()` function will invariably return a string. What you want to do is have the user input several numbers (presumably separated by a space) and get a list of integer values from that. You can do that as follows (with some explanations on my part):

```
student_scores_string = input('Input a list of student scores: ')
```

(That line will just get a string inputted by the user.)

```
student_scores = student_scores_string.split()
```

(That line will give you a list, with each item in the list being one of the values inputted by the user, with a space as a separator.)

```
student_scores = [int(x) for x in student_scores]
```

(That line will loop over the elements in the `student_scores` list, turn each of them into an inetger - remember, so far we have strings! - and put that into the list.)

Then you can continue with your code.

Comment: If *input()* returns it **always** returns a string - not invariably

Comment: @Vlad, indeed. You can, of course, cast the input into another data type. I used "invariably" as a synonym for "always" without considering that, in a programming context, it might be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the input is in the form '25 30 23' - i.e., a string with integer tokens and whitespace delimiters

```py
scores = input('Input a list of student scores: ')
print('The highest score is', max(map(int, scores.split())))
```

**Output:**

```
The highest score is 30
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to **split** the input as list, cause `student_scores` is a string and does not support item assignment (immutable). Assuming the input separated by space:

```
student_scores = input('Input a list of student scores: ').split()
for n in range(0, len(student_scores)):
    student_scores[n] = int(student_scores[n])
print(student_scores)

highest = 0
for scores in student_scores:
    if highest < scores:
        highest = scores
print(f'The highest score is {highest}')
```

To get the highest value, you can use `highest = max(student_scores)`:

```
print(student_scores := [int(n) for n in input('Input a list of student scores: ').split()])
highest = max(student_scores)
print(f'The highest score is {highest}')
```

Or:

```
highest = max([int(n) for n in input('Input a list of student scores: ').split()])
print(f'The highest score is {highest}')
```

Comment: I just found this is right. The half tutorial clip was cut, so I couldn't see the split part. Now, I can see why.
Thank you!

Comment: Don’t mention it. You can accept the answer as if it satisfied you, or you can change 'accepted answer' of others answer later if it might better solution for your problem. stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers